# TypeError: mute_error() missing 1 required positional argument: 'ctx'

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm making a bot that will send error when BadArgument Or MissingRequirdArgument
But it send me this error:

```
TypeError: mute_error() missing 1 required positional argument: 'ctx'
```

Code:

```
@mute.error
async def mute_error(error, ctx):
    if isinstance(error, MissingPermissions):
        await ctx.send(f"Sorry, you do not have permissions to do that!")
    
@mute_error
async def mute_error2(error, ctx):    
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
        await ctx.send("Please type !bot/mute 'mention member to mute'")
```

Comment: Is this code inside of the cog/class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are seeing an error because you are using your `mute_error` function as a [decorator](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/decorators-in-python/) for `mute_error2`.

What you have:

```
@mute_error
async def mute_error2(error, ctx):
```

What you probably meant, if you wish to match the decorator on the preceding function:

```
@mute.error
async def mute_error2(error, ctx):
```

For a slightly deeper explanation, you are passing the function `mute_error2` as the `error` argument to `mute_error`. No other arguments are being passed, so the `ctx` argument is not fulfilled, and you received the error.

Comment: thanks because i doesn't see that 'typo'

Answer (score -1):

also, the code is unnecessary longer, it will also just work with

```
@mute.error
async def mute_error(error, ctx):
    if isinstance(error, MissingPermissions):
        await ctx.send(f"Sorry, you do not have permissions to do that!")
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
        await ctx.send("Please type !bot/mute 'mention member to mute'")
```

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer